# EIP-155: are ERC-20 transactions protected from replays on different chains?

Tags: solidity

It seems that signatures conforming to the EIP-155 standard could not be replayed on different chains. However, some people think that it only protects transferring the chain currency (ETH). After all, if you make an ERC-20 transfer, could that transfer be replayed in other chains? (Given the other necessary nonce, gas conditions.)